# ajax: loading data in the background or creating a new sql table

Tags: asp.net, database-design, data-structures

I am making a website where users can see photos uploaded,
In any page, the users can click a button and "see three more photos", this is limited up to 100 photos per webpage.

basically I can use ajax to read the next 3 rows from the photos table, and load them to the user using ajax, but, while the user is browsing the site, the DB is most likely to have already been updated, and changed.

I have come up with two solutions and I can't decide between the two:

1. use ajax to load in the background first 100 items into an array (just the urls of the photos), and use javascript to display them on the page when the user click the "see three more"
2. create a new temporary table in my db, containing the first 100 rows, so I could access every time with ajax, while I'll know it will not change by another user uploading a new photo.

the goal is to find a way that will not be too time consuming for the server (in case there are a lot of requests and many temporary tables will have to be created),
and also a way that will not be too heavy and bandwidth consuming for the user (I don't want to load 10 MB of stuff to the clients browser "just in case" he will push a button).

which option would be the better one?
is there a third option i'm not thinking about?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that creating temporary tables isn't a good solution for the reasons you have already mentioned; you'll be doing a lot of cleanup work and you're not really solving your other problem, which is heavy bandwidth consumption.

I think the problem is your user experience expectation, which I'm not really clear on.

So - I'm a user of your site, I go to a page and see some (how many?) photos - with a button that says "see 3 more". I click it and see *the next* 3 photos, loaded using AJAX.

Does it matter if there are 50 new photos added in between each time click "see 3 more" ? Surely I want to see the next 3, not the newest 3 ?

Loading "the next 3 via AJAX" doesn't mean you have to preload the 100 URL's into a client-side array; just keep the most recent Image ID or most recent date/time client side, and pass this to your server-side function in "see 3 more"; should be straightforward enough to return the next most recent 3 URL's (if there are any) and then update your "current" Image ID.

Does that help ?

Comment: yes and no. but thanks for the answer.

if I will be displaying photos from newest to oldest, then, you are right, there is no problem posting the images based on the last image id used, but if I post them based on "highest ranked" to "lowest ranked" then the ImageID is useless to me since it does not correspond with the image's rank. this is why I thought of purging my table to a new temp table with new ID based on the ranking of the photo and thus I would be able to utilize the same method. if I do not create a custom table I can't see how this would be possible.